# Having diffuclties deploying my fast-api to aws lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

this is the code which i am trying to host on AWS, ->[https://github.com/Husseinmdarman/BookContentToYoutubeVideos][code base]

However for the life of me I am struggling, so what i have tried to do is create a lambda function on AWS then once that was created, the mangum handler which is wrapped around my fast-api app

with in my `main.py` file I have the following code written to handle all the lambda wrapping

```
app = FastAPI()
handler = Mangum(app)
```

Now on AWS lambda you would have to configure the handler, so through reading i assumed since my file is main.py and the handler is just called handler, that i would be okay to just select main.handler. However the problems i soon ran into were

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'main'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "3f597b25-74db-4db5-9c9a-788782883812",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Could it be because i'm just directly ziping up my code base and uploading a zip on to lambda, the only issue I cannot see on the inline code bit because my zipped file is 8mb, yeah i believe it might be the way i zipped my files, i jsut ran the normal compress on windows [Update this didn't work]

So instead what i tried was

1. `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
2. Then went to my WSL terminal and did `sudo apt install python3-pip`
3. `(cd dep; zip ../lambda_artifact.zip -r .)` which downloads all the external dependaces and zips it into a lambda artifact
   4.`zip lambda_artifact.zip -u main.py`  Then added my main file to the artifact, same way with all my other .py files

Now the new error i'm getting is

```
"Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'",
```

which suggests that there is not _pydantic_core but when i have a look at the installed dependicies i do see it in the folder

[image: dependcies]

By checking the lambda zip,  I can see it in there too
[image: lambda zip]

Comment: are you sure `main` is at the top of the directory structure in the zipfile?

Comment: @erik258 I believe that may be the issue but i'll update my question

Comment: I don't see a main in there

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering (`"Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'main'"`) suggests that AWS Lambda cannot find the `main.py` file in the root of your zipped deployment package.

1. **Check your project structure again**

Ensure that your `main.py` file is at the root of your zipped file. The thing is your zipped file shouldn't contain the project folder itself as the top-level directory.

```py
main.py
other_module.py
requirements.txt
venv/
...
```

2. **Lambda configuration**

Please ensure that

- You've set the **Runtime** to a Python version that matches your development environment.
- In the **Handler** field, you've entered `main.handler` (as your file name is `main.py`) and your Mangum instance is named `handler`).

Comment: To answer the second part, I am running on python 3.12 which is the same as my evn and thats correct, i named it main and handler, Although the first part of your question is prehaps where there is a issue. I'll update my issue, please have a look in a few minutes

Comment: I don't think lambda supports 3.12 yet.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/aws-lambda-support-python-3-12/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple FastAPI code as below in python 3.12 and it is executing on local environement.

1. Created a folder name test and created main.py file as below in IDLE.
2. Installed the dependencies using[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oA3e.png). (fastapi, mangum,uvicorn)
3. moved the main.py file into dependencies folder and zipped all dependencies.
4. renamed it to main.zip and uploaded in AWS lambda.

when tried to test, getting below error though it is present in the same hierarchy.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "d47131a7-5300-4f7c-9855-9967b1872f1e",
  "stackTrace": []
}



from fastapi import FastAPI
from mangum import Mangum

app = FastAPI()
handler = Mangum(app)
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello from Lambda"}
```

Comment: The most recent release of Pydantic triggers an error when executing the code on AWS Lambda. I encountered the same issue and resolved it by updating the requirements.txt file as follows:

fastapi==0.99.0
mangum

Answer (score 0):

@j stevenage,

Please use below dependencies in your requirements.txt file
fastapi==0.99.0
mangum

The latest version is triggering the error